# DismissModaViewController on Mail composer not working

Tags: mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a problem when i finished a screenshot and try to email out the screenshot in an app. Normally it works perfectly when sending text, but once sending screenshot, no matter cancel or sent the email, the screen won't go away. May I know what is the problem of this?

Here is my code. Thank you very much.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

        if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

        if ( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
            MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
            mailComposer.delegate = self;
            [mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"attachment.jpg"];

            /* Configure other settings */

            [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The delegate method you need to implement is `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:`, not `mailComposeController:`. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks. However, the screen ended up same as before. The mail composer just don't go away.

Comment: The problem has been solved by changing the delegate to mailComposeDelegate.